# Title Hero or titular/eponymous hero?

Tags: adjectives

Jane Eyre is the *title* of a novel. The *hero* of the novel is called Jane Eyre. Can you say "Jane Eyre is the *title hero* of the novel"? I know that *titular hero* or *eponymous hero* is correct, however I'm focusing on the noun+noun phrase here. Any input welcome :-) Thanks!

Comment: You can say it and people will know what you mean, but adjectives exist for a reason. Titular exists, why force title?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't the warmest welcome. Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

*Title* is the noun and *titular* is the adjective, as you know and (*subjectivity warning!*) I would encourage using adjectives as adjectives and nouns as nouns*.

There is, however, precedent for using the noun-noun construction.

Since the 1960s use of *titular hero* has declined while *title hero* has increased.

[image: NGram of 'title hero' vs 'titular hero']

This perhaps follows the use of *title hero* which is far more common than *titular character* and has been for a long time.

[image: Ngram of 'title character' vs 'titular character']

*I would appreciate comment, edit or additional solution which addresses the part of speech of *title* in *title hero*. I expect it is not a noun marauding as an adjective, but I am not well enough versed in grammar.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot - interesting statistics, how did you get them?

Comment: Whoops didn't link. They're from Google Ngrams—really fun tool. Questionably reliable but gives a good rough picture. Graph of word use in Google Books. Check it out!